# How can I list files and directories with them directory levels

Tags: c#, collections, directory

I have a directory tree with files. I would like to create a list which contains all files with a number(which means the level of them), for example:

```
RootDir
  file_1
  file_2
  Dir_a
    file_a1
    file_a2
    Dir_b
      file_b1
      file_b2
```

So I mean file_1 and file_2 have the number 1, cause they're on the 1st level. file_a1, and file_a2 have "2" etc... But I can't find out a collection which can contains this with these parameters. I thought about a dictionary, but it's impossible because a filename can be multiplied on different levels, and the level number is also multiplied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can use file path as key and level number as value using dictionary.

and parse the file path string to calculate level number, use string.split

```
string[] words = s.Split('\\');
```

Comment: truly. I don't know why, but I forgot, that I get the filename with path. Now I can d this :) . Many thanks.